# JAVA - GridBagLayout layout issue

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller, gridbaglayout

I am currently learning the MVC pattern and so I decided to create my own calculator in Java and in my `View.java`, I have the following code.

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class View extends JFrame {

private Controller theController;
    public JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("0");

    public View () {

    }

    //public void open (Controller theController) {
    //  this.theController = theController;
    //  init();
    //  setVisible(true);
    //}

    private void init () {

        this.setTitle("Calculator");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel calculatorPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        calculatorPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        resultLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        resultLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        resultLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 25));
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        // For the fix, changed this constraint to fill BOTH X & Y axis.  
        // gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        calculatorPanel.add(resultLabel, gbc);

        // and then removed this following code:
        // gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;

        String commandsList[] = {"←", "±", "√", "%", "1/x", "CE", "C", "="};
        for(String commandName : commandsList) {
            JButton command = new JButton(commandName);
        //  command.addActionListener(theController.actionListener());
            switch(commandName) {
                case "←":
                case "±":
                case "√":
                case "%":
                case "1/x":
                    gbc.gridy = 1;
                    break;
                case "CE":
                    gbc.gridy = 2;
                    gbc.gridx = 4;
                    break;
                case "C":
                    gbc.gridy = 3;
                    gbc.gridx = 4;
                    break;
                case "=":
                    gbc.gridy = 4;
                    gbc.gridx = 4;
                    gbc.gridheight = 2;
                    break;
            }
            calculatorPanel.add(command, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
        }
        // and changed the overlooked `gridheight` back to 1
        // so I added this 1 line of code:
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;

        JButton[] Btns = new JButton[10];
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            Btns[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
        //  Btns[i].addActionListener(theController.actionListener());
            if(i==0) { 
                gbc.gridy = 5;
                gbc.gridwidth = 3;
            }   
            if(i>=1 && i<=3) {
                gbc.gridy = 4;
                if(i==1) gbc.gridx = 0;
                if(i==2) gbc.gridx = 1;
                if(i==3) gbc.gridx = 2;
            }
            if(i>=4 && i<=6) {
                gbc.gridy = 3;
                if(i==4) gbc.gridx = 0;
                if(i==5) gbc.gridx = 1;
                if(i==6) gbc.gridx = 2;
            }
            if(i>=7 && i<=9) {
                gbc.gridy = 2;
                if(i==7) gbc.gridx = 0;
                if(i==8) gbc.gridx = 1;
                if(i==9) gbc.gridx = 2;
            }

            calculatorPanel.add(Btns[i], gbc);
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        }

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        String operatorsList[] = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};
        for(String operatorName : operatorsList) {
            JButton operator = new JButton(operatorName);
        //  operator.addActionListener(theController.actionListener());
            calculatorPanel.add(operator, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
        }

        this.add(calculatorPanel);
        this.pack();
    }
}
```

<s>My problem is, I cant make the components align themselves properly using 'GridBagLayout' and 'GridBagConstraints' as discussed in this page, [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), in building the UI.</s>

Problem is, with my code, the components end up overlapping each other and seemed scattered around in its container.

**I like loops I know :)

EDIT: I finally was able to fix it, re-read the documentation and found the problem I'm missing out on. FIX REFLECTED ON CODE w/ comments

Comment: Are you using an IDE or creating all by hand?

Comment: the latest version of Eclipse is what I am currently using.

Comment: nvm, found the flaw. it's the `fill` constraint and an overlook `gridheight`

Comment: Done, as per requested by @EthanMoore. Thanks.